# Configure Tesla K20m on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have a Tesla k20m and I want to do some experiments with CUDA on my PC. I used the Nvidia instruccions for install the drivers and CUDA 8:

1. Disable nouveau driver
2. Reboot into text mode (runlevel 3)
3. Run the installer

The installation of drivers and CUDA finish succefull and I can execute the sample files to verify the correct installation.

The problem is when I try to enable the nouveau driver. If I enable the nouveau diver the nvdidia drivers for Tesla k20m doesn't work and I can not execute the samples.

The idea is to use the noveau driver with the intel integrated graphics and the nvidia drivers for the Tesla k20m.

Is it possible? Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The nouveau driver can't drive intel integrated graphics, so there is no reason to enable it in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible since the nouveau driver replaces the nvidia driver. But the intel driver should work together with the nvidia driver.

I dont know the concrete name of the package for the intel driver, since i use a other distro but you may be lucky if you google it.